# Alignment of chapter, section and subsection in memoir class

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir, chapters

I was wondering if there is a neat way of aligning the chapter, section and subsection headings in `memoir` class so as to look like this:

[image]

(the largest heading at the top is the chapter, etc.)

Comment: What code have you got? What have you tried? Please provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example provides a length `\secnumwidth` that is used to fix the widths within which the section numbers (including that of `\chapter`) is printed. All other display styles have been preserved (including the vertical spacing for `\chapter`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\setlength{\secnumwidth}{3em}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}% Don't print 'Chapter'
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}[1]{\makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}% Remove (vertical) skip between chapter number and title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}% Number up to \subsection

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's a similar way to achieve it in the default `report` document class. It involves updating `\@makechapterhead` and `\@seccntformat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\setlength{\secnumwidth}{5em}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\interlinepenalty\@M
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \huge\bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{\thechapter}%
    \fi
     #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

Like before, the regular vertical spacing for `\chapter` has been preserved (but could be changed).